# how to cast content to context

Tags: android

**Logcat**

> 05-15 12:19:53.718 1622-1622/com.ahmed.new_final E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: com.ahmed.new_final, PID: 1622
>                                                                      java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ahmed.new_final.activity.Teacher_add_updateActivity$1 cannot be cast to android.content.Context
>                                                                          at com.ahmed.new_final.database.DBHeleper.(DBHeleper.java:31)
>                                                                          at com.ahmed.new_final.activity.Teacher_add_updateActivity$1.onClick(Teacher_add_updateActivity.java:46)
>                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**DBhelper.java**

```
public DBHeleper(View.OnClickListener context) {
    super((Context) context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEACHER + "( "
            + KEY_TEACHER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_TEACHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TEACHER_POST + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TEACHER_PHONE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TEACHER_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TEACHER_OFFICE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TEACHER_OFFICE_HOURS + " TEXT)"
    );
}
```

**Addteacher.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teacher_add_update);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    edname = findViewById(R.id.edname);
    edpost = findViewById(R.id.edpost);
    edphone = findViewById(R.id.edphone);
    edemail = findViewById(R.id.edemail);
    edoffice= findViewById(R.id.edoffice);
    edofficehour= findViewById(R.id.edofficehour);


    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = edname.getText().toString();
            String post = edpost.getText().toString();
            String phone = edphone.getText().toString();
            String email = edemail.getText().toString();
            String  office= edoffice.getText().toString();
            String officehour= edofficehour.getText().toString();

            Teacher teacher = new Teacher(name, post, phone, email, office, officehour);


            DBHeleper dbHeleper = new DBHeleper(this);

            long result= dbHeleper.AddTeacher(teacher);
            if(result != -1)
                Toast.makeText(Teacher_add_updateActivity.this, "Add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(Teacher_add_updateActivity.this, "Faild", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to cast anything . `Activity` itself is a `Context`.

Just make these statements right .

```
DBHeleper dbHeleper = new DBHeleper(Addteacher.this);
```

And your constructor should be as

```
public DBHeleper(Context context) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }
```

Comment: tnx A lot Adm sir

Comment: @ahmed if this answer helped you can accept it by clicking on the check button next to it :)